# UIL LinearBackground image not working

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, universal-image-loader, setbackground

I've spent half day reading documentation and examples. I can't find a solution.
I've a ListView in an Activity, each item has LinearLayout with a background image loaded with Android-Universal-Image-Loader by nostr13.

I use this library to put a LinearBackground image as a background. In my Activity I download a JSON, parsing and creating a String array with the URIs.

The problem is the print done by the library is wrong! It works fine with ImageView but if I use LinearBackground with loadImage() intestead of displayImage() it doesn't put correctly the backgrounds. The procees seen at slow motion is like: create the right number of elements (4), place the first loaded image as background of one row, then once another image is loaded the library replaces the old background with this new image, different, then it places another image and stop. This is an example of the bug. It's always different!!! Some of them are empty but the onLoadingComplete event is called. I thought it was a problem of cache and I've played with the UIL's options without luck. Images are just 4 and very small (<10kb each).

I set the adapter in the onPostExecute event, is it ok?

What can be the problem?

Here the important code:

The Activity code (i've removed not relevant code to help to find the problem):

```
    public class myActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;

    // Output Vars
    String mStrings[];
    ListView listView;

    // UIL
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stagioni);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.fail)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.fail)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .build();


        startAsynkTask(context);
    }
    public void startAsynkTask(final Context context) {

          AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
          private ProgressDialog pd;
          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
                   pd = new ProgressDialog(ActivityStagioni.this);
                   pd.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_loading));
                   pd.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_loading_stagioni));
                   pd.setCancelable(true);
                   pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                   pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                   pd.show();
          }
          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
              //... Not relevant code ...
          }
          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                  pd.dismiss();

                   ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                    {               
                        //... Not relevant code ...
                    });
          }
  };
    task.execute();   
      }



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            ImageLoader imageLoader;

            public ImageAdapter() {

                imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mStrings.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                //ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();


                final ViewHolder holder;
                View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) {
                    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stagioni_item, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    assert view != null;
                    holder.imageView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutLocandina);
                    holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
                    view.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                }

                imageLoader.loadImage(mStrings[position], new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    //final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
                        //if (loadedImage != null) {
                        //  boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                        //  if (firstDisplay) {
                                BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(loadedImage);
                                holder.imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
                            //}
                    //  }

                    }
                });

                return view;
            }
```

The ListView item is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLocandina"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="5" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="0"
           android:alpha="1"
           android:background="#80000000" >

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
               android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_NumeroStagione"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:text="30"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>



           <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_NomeStagione"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_NumeroEpisodi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_objectID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        style="@style/ProgressBarStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Application

```
    public class MyAppName extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        initImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you may tune some of them,
                // or you can create default configuration by
                //  ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
                // method.
                ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                        .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
                        .build();
                // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
                ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
}
```

Logcat
http://pastebin.com/JejB8miC

Thanks for support

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 'universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources.jar'.

Comment: Use `DisplayImageOptions.resetViewBeforeLoading(...)` or `.showImageOnLoading(...)`.

Comment: I've added DisplayImageOptions.resetViewBeforeLoading and it's the same. The property 'showImageOnLoading' is already in the config, can you see my options in the post? Do you have any other suggestions? I really want to use your library in my project. Priviet for you help.

Comment: Ok, it seems I got it. I think you should use `ImageAware`, create your own implementation (like `ImageViewAware`) which wraps `LinearLayout` and use it with `displayImage(...)` method. I'll add the answer with code sample later.

Answer (score 1):

Add this `ImageAware` into your project:

```
public class BgImageAware implements ImageAware {

    public static final String WARN_CANT_SET_DRAWABLE = "Can't set a drawable into view. You should call ImageLoader on UI thread for it.";
    public static final String WARN_CANT_SET_BITMAP = "Can't set a bitmap into view. You should call ImageLoader on UI thread for it.";

    protected Reference<View> viewRef;
    protected boolean checkActualViewSize;

    public BgImageAware(View view) {
        this(view, true);
    }

    public BgImageAware(View view, boolean checkActualViewSize) {
        this.viewRef = new WeakReference<View>(view);
        this.checkActualViewSize = checkActualViewSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        View view = viewRef.get();
        if (view != null) {
            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            int width = 0;
            if (checkActualViewSize && params != null && params.width != ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
                width = view.getWidth(); // Get actual image width
            }
            if (width <= 0 && params != null) width = params.width; // Get layout width parameter
            return width;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        View view = viewRef.get();
        if (view != null) {
            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            int height = 0;
            if (checkActualViewSize && params != null && params.height != ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
                height = view.getHeight(); // Get actual image height
            }
            if (height <= 0 && params != null) height = params.height; // Get layout height parameter
            return height;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewScaleType getScaleType() {
        return ViewScaleType.CROP;
    }

    @Override
    public View getWrappedView() {
        return viewRef.get();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCollected() {
        return viewRef.get() == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        View view = viewRef.get();
        return view == null ? super.hashCode() : view.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            View view = viewRef.get();
            if (view != null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    view.setBackground(drawable);
                } else {
                    view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                }
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            L.w(WARN_CANT_SET_DRAWABLE);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            View view = viewRef.get();
            if (view != null) {
                Drawable drawable = bitmap == null ? null : new BitmapDrawable(view.getResources(), bitmap);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    view.setBackground(drawable);
                } else {
                    view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                }
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            L.w(WARN_CANT_SET_BITMAP);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then wrap your `LinearLayout` into it and pass to `displayImage(...)` method:

```
ImageAware imageAware = new BgImageAware(holder.imageView);
imageLoader.displayImage(mStrings[position], imageAware);
```

Comment: I've added this class and used displayImage method and it works fine. You're a good man. Thank you very much. Do you accept donations? Dassvidania

Comment: You're welcome. Donation info here - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#donation